# How to give domain name to your server

Tags: web, server, hosting

I don't know how well i am asking this question but can someone tell me how do i give a domain name to my server . I mean right now i can just access it by an ip . But i want it to be accessed by a name. When we purchase a hosting plan we already are give a domain name . But how to have a domain name when you already have your own server?

Answer (score 0):

1]Login into Control Panel of your Domain Registrar

2]There you will have facility to Register Name Server.(ns1.domainname = IP of your server and ns2.domainname = IP of your server). Ask your Domain registrar to have step by step guide about How to register name server? and perform accordingly.

3]Open DNS manager with your Server and make entry of your domain.

4]Global propagation will take 24-48 hours time, and your domain 
will start pointing to your server.

Comment: thanx for the answer , as soon as i try this . I'll get back to u :)